# How do I detect a store checkout page with a chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, e-commerce

I am developing a chrome extension where I would like to show a popup to my users whenever they visit an e-commerce store's checkout page. I understand one option is to get a list of checkout page URLs for all the merchants I support, then detect that page with my extension but it would be a pain to gather thousands of URLs.

**Is there some easy method for detecting a store's checkout page?**

Also, as a bonus question, do you have any ideas for how I could detect a store's confirmation page? Without gathering a list of URLs or regex matches.

Comment: You could try checking for any payment gateways

Comment: Good idea! How would you go about that? I suppose I could make a list of the most popular PGs and look for them in the DOM, but I might miss some of the more obscure PGs that way.

Comment: Well that may be your only option. You could use the inspect element tool to see the source code of honey (the chrome extension), and see how they do it

Comment: Another good idea! I will give this a try, thanks.